# Two projects, a derived class should be able to access one method but not the other one

Tags: c#, oop

I was asked this question in interview, but couldn't answer it.

There are two projects: P1 and P2

P1 has a class A with methods M1 and M2

P2 has a class B and class C, both of these classes (inherit or reference)* from class A in Project P1

Class B should be able to access method M1 but not M2
Class C should be able to access method M2 but not M1

*I don't remember if he said inherit or said reference

How can this be done?

Comment: Please, share your code and classes

Comment: I believe this is a question about understanding the problem, and not about implementing it. You have tools such as protected, internal, interfaces, but if the understanding is that the things you set up in P1 **prevents** the two classes in P2 from doing what you want them not to do, then no, you can't do that. But if you want to design the two classes in P2 such that they only have access to the methods they should, then yes, you can do that, but this is partly done in P2.

Comment: It sounds like a poorly phrased question. From one point of view it's impossible. If class B  can access a method but class C can't, you can always change the code in class C so that it does whatever class B does. The question implies that it's about limiting or preventing access, but it isn't. "Should be able to access" could mean anything. A class either allows or prevents access to a method.

Comment: My answer in the interview would be, "Why would you want to do something so weird and confusing?"

Answer (score 1):

You want to use interfaces to extract methods from class.

**P1:**

```cs
public interface IM1
{
  void M1();
}

public interface IM2
{
  void M2();
}

// Not public
internal class A : IM1, IM2
{
   public void M1() {} 
   public void M2() {}
}
```

**P2:**

```cs
public class B
{
   private readonly IM1 _m1;
}

public class C
{
   private readonly IM2 _m2;
}
```

Comment: But here, class B and C does not inherit from class A

Comment: @teenup You have mentioned `inherit or reference` in the question, this answer uses reference approach. You can not achieve what you want to achieve by using inheritance.

Comment: I am not sure if this is the solution. Because, even if the interviewer said 'reference', he used the statement (reference A), and not the individual interfaces. I am hoping to have some other answer for this.

Comment: How will the _m1 be called from class B here? Can you please explain.

Comment: @teenup it's impossible to hide functions using inheritance. Using composition, you still reference A, but only have access to the interface part of it (if `A` is public, you could updast it `(_m1 as A) != null`). You can call `_m1` as any other regular object??

Comment: In this example one class uses one method and another class uses another method. But either class is *able* to use either method if you modify the class. In other words, nothing prevents class `B` or `C` from referencing both `IM1` *and* `IM2` and calling either method. For that reason I don't think it answers the question.

Comment: `"In other words, nothing prevents class B or C from referencing both IM1 and IM2 and calling either method"`... If you give yourself the freedom to modify the code, anything is possible. And the question becomes unanswerable. HOWEVER, if you don't change it, it's most likely what the interviewers were trying to get out of you.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement some like: https://dotnetfiddle.net/0mYxdU

```
public interface InterfaceCommon
{
    void Function();
}

public class Implementacion1 : InterfaceCommon
{
    public void Function()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I am Method1");
    }
}

public class Implementacion2 : InterfaceCommon
{
    public void Function()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I am Method2");
    }
}

public abstract class A
{
    private readonly InterfaceCommon interfaceCommon;

    protected A(InterfaceCommon interfaceCommon)
    {
        this.interfaceCommon = interfaceCommon;
    }

    public void  CallFunction()
    {
        interfaceCommon.Function();
    }

}


public class B : A
{
   public B() : base(new Implementacion1()) {  }

}

public class C : A
{
    public C() : base(new Implementacion2()) { }

}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var b = new B();
        b.CallFunction();
        var c = new C();
        c.CallFunction();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, [Strategy Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) would also work.